# Search query in a react app without backend

Tags: reactjs, search

Has anyone made a react website with static data that does not have a backend to store information, but needs to add a query/search functionality in the front end that can fetch information(a specific keyword that can be present on multiple pages of the app) from the entire app?

What I am looking for is, an option to store the data and made a query from there without implementing a backend from scratch. Is that possible?  From my research so far, what I have found so far is I need to store all the information to some storage services like Firebase or Firestore and need to retrieve data from the entire app and only thenI can implement search functionality using third-party apps like typesense or algolia. But did not find any specific example based on that. I am a beginner in react, so any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like a built-in JSON data file within the app that can be imported into a component to be referenced/searched/filtered/etc?

Comment: You can easily store data just as a `mydata.json` file and then load it using `fetch`. If you load the json in the root `App` component, it will be available in the whole app. Firebase and such is only needed if you want to manipulate the data and then store it on the server again.

Comment: @Drew Reese
Say, for example, I have a paragraph tag like this in several pages of the app (<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>) where I am hardcoding the information without fetching data from a backend server or database and I want to find all the pages that has the keyword "Lorem" in there by typing "Lorem" in the search input located in my home page, then how can I achieve them?

Comment: @Kokodoko, thanks for the information. Just to clarify, should I store data of all the components that I have in my app in the same JSON file and fetch it from there?

Comment: You want to search your app's rendered output for specific key words? If all the content is hardcoded then I suppose you'll be searching your source code. If the content is stored in a JSON then you only need to search that. BTW, you don't need to fetch the JSON file if it's a local asset, you can just import it normally. It's much simpler than setting up the lifecycle to fetch it and handle storing the response.

Comment: For simplicity's sake you can start with calling `fetch()` in the root `App` component. Then you can use `props` to give the data to any child component that needs it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the prompt response, I will definitely try that.

Comment: If all you're doing is searching your HTML, then look no further than [`Document API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), more specifically, `document.querySelector`. There are also data structures you can look into. One such datastructure is the [`trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) datastructure which allows you to do fast prefix queries. You can generate one as part of a seperate build process to store an index of keywords that relate to certain pages/ids on your website. Serialize it to json or xml, then fetch it when needed to carry out the actual search.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Local Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save data on the frontend.
You can store a JSON object as string in the localstorage using

```
localStorage.setItem('my-key', jsonObjectString);
```

Later you can retrieve the object using

```
const textFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('my-key');
let jsonObject = JSON.parse(textFromStorage)
// Now you can do your query here
```